# Decent routine to check server certificate

Tags: ssl, starttls

I am writing a client app that need talk to Active Directory server and one of requirements is to support LDAPS/StartTLS.
I already figure out there is one option need to set:

```
if (ldap_set_option(pLdap, LDAP_OPT_SERVER_CERTIFICATE, &my_cert_check_func) != LDAP_SUCCESS) {
    std::cerr << "ldap set cert check callback failed" <<std::endl;
    return NULL;
}
```

and my_cert_check_func is over-naive and not safe at all:

```
static BOOLEAN my_cert_check_func(PLDAP connection, PCCERT_CONTEXT server_cert)
{
    return TRUE;
}
```

And I also did a lot of googling and read quite a lot msdn, but still no clue. I have never handle such security-related coding before so any thing related to cert check are welcome.
And because I write this app using Winldap API, so the code should use Windows specific APIs.

And I am also thinking do such check using openssl api (this api is a dependency of my app, so it is fine to use that).

Could you show me some sample code for doing real checking of server certs against client security store or what ever client has?

Thank you very much!

Comment: What library are you using? `ldap_set_option` is *not* part of the Windows API. You might consider using the library for the validation (assuming it has the functionality). Otherwise, you need to determine your security requirements, determine which are not provided by the library, and then list those you want to implement.

Comment: *"ldap set cert check callback failed"* - should be a wide string because you are using `werr`. You should probably enable warnings as a first step.

Comment: yes, @jww. thank you pointing that. I updated code.
And I only use windows native LDAP lib. that is winldap.h and wldap32.lib

Comment: @jww Strange that [MSDN is full of documentation about it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa367019(v=vs.85).aspx) then. Your explanation?

Comment: @EJP - explanation for what?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to verify the entire certificate chain etc. for validity. LDAPS should already have done that. You only need to check the subjectDN of the certificate against what you think it should be when talking to that server.